# Calling a flask application from djangocms

Tags: python, flask, django-cms

I have the following flask app that takes a 36 slider answers, from a form and outputs a simple multiplication result

flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import jinja2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/quest')
def index():
    # Render the form. Nothing special needs to happen here.
    return render_template('/aboutImgFree.html')


@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def results():
if request.method == 'POST':
    likertValues = {'C1': [request.values['vol1'], request.values['vol2'],request.values['vol3'], request.values['vol4'], 
    request.values['vol5'],request.values['vol6']], 
    'C2': [request.values['vol7'], request.values['vol8'], request.values['vol9'], request.values['vol10'],
     request.values['vol11'], request.values['vol12']],
    'C3': [request.values['vol13'], request.values['vol14'], request.values['vol15'], request.values['vol16']
    , request.values['vol17'], request.values['vol18']],
    'C4': [request.values['vol19'], request.values['vol20'], request.values['vol21'], request.values['vol22']
    , request.values['vol23'], request.values['vol24']],
    'C5': [request.values['vol25'], request.values['vol26'], request.values['vol27'], request.values['vol28']
    , request.values['vol29'], request.values['vol30']],
    'C6': [request.values['vol31'], request.values['vol32'], request.values['vol33'], request.values['vol34']
    , request.values['vol35'], request.values['vol36']]}


    io = pd.DataFrame(data=likertValues)
    io_t = io.astype('int64')

    factor={'factor':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
    f=pd.DataFrame(data=factor)
    
    #return render_template('/results.html',io=io.to_html(),f=type(f.iloc[-1,-1]))
    ''' 
    io_table=pd.read_csv(request.files['io_table'])

    io_t=io_table
    factor=pd.read_csv(request.files['factor'])
    f=factor
    ''' 
    mdl1=pd.DataFrame(io_t.values+f.values, columns=io_t.columns, index=io_t.columns)
    mdl2=pd.DataFrame(io_t.values*f.values, columns=io_t.columns, index=io_t.columns)
    c_sum1 = mdl1.sum(axis=0)
    r_sum1 = mdl1.sum(axis=1)

    c_sum2 = mdl2.sum(axis=0)
    r_sum2 = mdl2.sum(axis=1)

    mdl1_t=mdl1
    mdl2_t=mdl2
    
    io_t.rename(index={0:'C1',1:'C2',2:'C3',3:'C4',4:'C5',5:'C6'},inplace=True)
    io_t.rename(columns={0:'C1',1:'C2',2:'C3',3:'C4',4:'C5',5:'C6'},inplace=True)

    mdl1_t=mdl1_t.append(c_sum1, ignore_index=True)
    mdl1_t.rename(index={0:'C1',1:'C2',2:'C3',3:'C4',4:'C5',5:'C6',6:'Sum Column'},inplace=True)
                    
    mdl1_t=pd.concat([mdl1_t, r_sum1], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
    mdl1_t.iloc[-1,-1]=mdl1.values.sum()
    mdl1_t.rename(columns={0:'C1',1:'C2',2:'C3',3:'C4',4:'C5',5:'C6',6:'Sum Row'},inplace=True)

    mdl2_t=mdl2_t.append(c_sum2, ignore_index=True)
    mdl2_t.rename(index={0:'C1',1:'C2',2:'C3',3:'C4',4:'C5',5:'C6',6:'Sum Column'},inplace=True)
          
    mdl2_t=pd.concat([mdl2_t, r_sum2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
    mdl2_t.iloc[-1,-1]=mdl2.values.sum()

    mdl2_t.rename(columns={0:'C1',1:'C2',2:'C3',3:'C4',4:'C5',5:'C6',6:'Sum Row'},inplace=True)

    option = request.form.getlist('model')
    if option == ['mdl1']:                
        return render_template('/results.html', io=io_t.to_html(), mdl1_t=mdl1_t.to_html())
    elif option == ['mdl2']:
        return render_template('/results.html', io=io_t.to_html(), mdl2_t=mdl2_t.to_html())
    elif option == ['mdl1','mdl2']:
        return render_template('/results.html', io=io_t.to_html(), mdl1_t=mdl1_t.to_html(), mdl2_t=mdl2_t.to_html())
    else:
        return render_template('/results.html', io=io_t.to_html())
    #results = new_io_table(io_table,factor) # Get some results
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What I want to do is take that code and call it from my `djangocms` application. Thing is that I can't find anywhere the answer and I don't know what exactly to look for. Is there anyone here that has done something similar?

I'm using django 3.x and flask 1.1.2

**UPDATE**

I found out about dispatching, which is really awesome, but I can't make it work correctly.

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound

from app1.website2 import app as app1
from app2 import app as app2

app = Flask(__name__)

app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(NotFound(), {
    "/app1": app1,
    "/quest": app2
})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\CMS\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 323, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\CMS\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 312, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\CMS\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\CMS\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\middleware\dispatcher.py", line 66, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by calling that code from djangocms? Do you want to transform your code so it works in Django? Or do you want to call it from Django, ie calling a link to a running Flask app?

Comment: I want to call my flask app as a link i.e www.djangoapp.com/flaskapp. Right now I've made some progress using dispatch and but I can't make it work. P.S I will clarify that I'm using dispatch right now in my original post.

Comment: I guess I would just serve both the Flask app and Django  behind a nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: I'm trying to serve them both, in a test environment, because a client asked me to do it, just so he can see it before the deployment